# Clustered index scan on a foreign key assertion

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, deadlock, assertion

I have a stored procedure that gets executed for any change to the objects in a table A(The stored procedure is triggered by an after update trigger). The stored procedure in turn updates a table B which has a foreign key reference to table A(and another table say Table C) and two indexes.

Now this stored procedure has a parameter passed which is the unique identifier of the table A so any access to the main table A is very row specific i.e it always affects only one row.

The same set up is across multiple projects in our system but the execution plan generated for one specific project is different from the others and I have narrowed down to the source of the issue. The execution plan is exactly the same up to the actual table insert(table B) but differs from there on for the index and foreign key assertions.

Here is a screen shot of a "good plan" where the foreign key assertions are done using a clustered index seek.

[Good plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9vCX.png)

Here's the execution plan for this particular project where we are seeing a lot of deadlocks and this is because there is a clustered index scan for these foreign key assertions. When I remove the foreign key the issue disappears. Why is there a scan here ? We have indexes on the foreign keys. Also why is the non clustered index inserts expanded in this plan? And what is the sequence operator doing ? I tried RECOMPILE and it generated the same plan with a scan for the foreign key update.

[Bad plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUy9w.png)

Comment: In some cases the query optimizer will choose a *scan* (for smaller tables or when a large percentage of the records match the predicate) over a *seek* if it is faster.